# Wordpress Meta query search

Tags: php, search, wordpress

I have custom Field named "motor_brand" of posts.This meta values saved as `["honda","suzuki","kawasaki","toyota"]`

If i search just honda by meta_query then all pos having honda meta value if iwant to search honda and kawasaki then the having honda or kawasaki meta values appear if i want to search kawasaki,honda and toyota then posts that having meta value honda, kawasaki or toyota can be appers.

I have set meta query like this

```
meta_ query = array(
     'relation'=>'OR'
       array(
        meta_key =>'motor_brand'
        value => "honda",
        compare => "LIKE"
        ),
       array(
        meta_key =>'motor_brand'
        value => "kawasaki",
        compare => "LIKE"
        ),
)
```

That works fine  but when i try

```
meta_ query = array(
     'relation'=>'OR'
       array(
        meta_key =>'motor_brand'
        value => "honda",
        compare => "LIKE"
        ),
       array(
        meta_key =>'motor_brand'
        value => "kawasaki",
        compare => "LIKE"
        ),
       array(
        meta_key =>'motor_brand'
        value => "toyota",
        compare => "LIKE"
        ),
)
```

That not work

i want to search to many motor brands

Comment: in both cases there is a missing `,` after `'relation' => 'OR'`

Comment: this code is write just for example to get the idea i have uses proper sentax the first case work correctly but if put search three times for same meta key that's faild.

Comment: what does fail mean? Please post the code which is not working and the resulting error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try this:

```
$meta_query = array(
   array(
       'key' => 'motor_brand',
       'value' => array('honda','kawasaki','toyota'), 
       'compare' => 'IN',
   )
);
```

It should produce `WHERE motor_brand IN ('honda','kawasaki','toyota')` and should show you results if you execute on your db directly.

**Edit**

Oh sorry, i saw you wrote

> I have custom Field named "motor_name" of posts.This meta values saved
>   as ["honda","suzuki","kawasaki","toyota"]

The `IN` doesnt work if you stored it like this. But what about `motor_name`. Your Field is named `motor_name` but your query asks for `motor_brand`.

Comment: Thanks for reply i sorry for writing mistake the meta key name is same alaround motor_brand i have already used IN compare. but i have solved  this in custom php my appling the condition after getting meta key value.but i think it is not a best solution